# query did not return a unique result: 4; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 4

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.MOCK)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
class LoginTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @MockBean
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Test
    void contextLoads() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/login"))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Welcome to Klaud")))
                .andExpect(content().string(containsString("Sign in")));
    }

    @Test
    void shouldSuccessfullyLogin() throws Exception {
        Role userRole = mock(Role.class);
        userRole.setRole("USER");

        User user = mock(User.class);
        user.setId(99);
        user.setFirstName("Donald");
        user.setLastName("Duck");
        user.setEmail("duck@gmail.com");
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode("12345678"));
        user.setActive(1);
        user.setRoles(new HashSet<>(Collections.singletonList(userRole)));
        userService.saveUser(user);

        mockMvc.perform(post("/login")
            .param("email", "test@gmail.com")
            .param("password", "test")
        ).andExpect(redirectedUrl("/home"));
    }
}
```

I'm struggling to write integration test for user login and getting this error when I want to save mocked user. How do I create a user and save to database?

Source code: https://github.com/camerons2001/Klaud

Fullstracktrace Error:

```
org.springframework.dao.IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException: query did not return a unique result: 4; nested exception is javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a unique result: 4

    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:385)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy114.findByRole(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
```

and more...

I'm using Spring Boot.

Comment: Why are you even trying to mock the user while you are writing an actual integration test? The mocked user doesn't contain anything (calling the setters does nothing) so you are storing an empty user. Also please add the full stacktrace to see where the error is coming from.

Comment: I'm trying to create a new user and want to check if the user has been created. Shouldn't user be mocked?

Comment: No, as calling the setters does nothing, so there is no data. The query that leads to the error is the `findByRole`. You have more users in your database with a certain role, where one is expected.

Comment: I tried to remove findByRole, but I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I doubt it is the exact same error. Unless you didn't remove it. I also dount that that is the full stactrace in yuor logs (there is too much missing from it).

Comment: I removed findByRole method from both UserServiceImpl and LoginTest. It turns out the problem is in user role. Should I remove it completely? I've got users role in database.

Comment: The problem is that you keep inserting the same role over and over, leading to this issue. Your entities should have an `equals`/`hashCode` for proper functioning and your role table shuld probably have a unique constraint on the role name. That being said even if that would work your test still wouldn't work.

Comment: Yes, I checked the database now and It has several user and same role in there. How should I approach the issue? Should I write equals/hashCode method in entity classes or is there any better solution?

Comment: Having a proper hashCode and equals is a must have for JPA also you need to protect yuor data from corruption so use constraints.

Comment: As I understand you mean I have to have unique roles in db?

Comment: Judging from your `findByRole` method yes. I assume you have 1 role `USER` which can belong to many users, and another `ADMIN` which belongs to other users (maybe they have both).

Comment: Yes, indeed, I think I've taken the code from not good resource as a result now I'm having a trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For the same row in the database table. please delete the duplicate data row from the table.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You better not set userId when you're mocking the user. It's bad practice and brings side effects. And you should roll back all db changes after your tests. Use @Transactional on the top of LoginTest class to rollback it after test execution.

Comment: https://github.com/camerons2001/Klaud/blob/master/src/main/java/com/kamron/klaud/model/User.java

Comment: You better not set userId when you're mocking the user. It's bad practice and brings side effects. And you should roll back all db changes after your tests. Use @Transactional on the top of LoginTest class

Comment: Sure, I remove setId. That's what I was thinking about, I need to create user for mocking and remove from database after the successful test pass.

Comment: @camerons2001 clean db, add annotation, remove set of userId and try again

Comment: The issue isn't related to setting the userid (nor will it have any effect as the User is a mock. Setting someting does nothing. Calling `getUserid` will return `null` or if a primitve the default for that. It is amock NOT a real user instance.